# SQL conditional order by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to sort a query of  tickets based first on whether they are open and second by descending order of creation. If I ticket is open it has a completed date of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. If it is closed it has the correct completed date. So the table has these fields (that are important):

- Tickets: {id (int), created (datetime), completed (datetime) }

I want any tickets that have a completed date of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to be at the top in reverse order of when they were created and then all closed tickets to simply be in reverse order below that.

My first attempt was:

```
select id, message
from tickets
where {{search conditions}}
ORDER BY tickets.created, tickets.id DESC;
```

But unfortunately, because the tickets.created field is a date time, I get the open tickets on top but the first closed ticket is the oldest ticket returned from the search. Is there some way I can make the order by statement conditional to give me all the open tickets and then give me the rest of the tickets in an `id` desc sort order?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If the condition is only on the `completed` column, why are you using `created` at all in your `order by`.  I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two keys in the `order by`:

```
order by (t.completed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00') desc,  -- put these first
         t.completed desc
```